# How to fix Error CA1307 with string.Contains(string, System.StringComparison)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my test I have assertion that contains `p.Contains(".Tests")` but it makes error

Error CA1307 `The behavior of 'string.Contains(string)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings. Replace this call in 'Solution.Tests.PackageTests._bowerEnabledProjects' with a call to 'string.Contains(string, System.StringComparison)'.`

So I wanted to fix it by: `p.Contains(".Tests", System.StringComparison)` but it makes error:

Error   CS0119  `'StringComparison' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`

Comment: Which should I use InvariantCulture or Ordinal?

Comment: @DiPix: That would normally be a question for you to decide having read the description of the various enum values. (For machine-generated text rather than human text, ordinal is *usually* a good approach; almost certainly for the tests you're writing.) However, that warning is basically invalid anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) is an enum - the warning suggests that you're meant to specify one of the values within that enum, e.g. `StringComparison.Ordinal`.

However, this warning is wrong on two counts:

- There *is* no `string.Contains(string, StringComparison)` method as far as I can see. The documentation for [`string.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) even gives an example of how you would implement such a method.
- The warning's claim that the behavior depends on the locale settings is incorrect. The documentation for `string.Contains` states: "This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison."

I would suggest disabling the warning.

Comment: Which should I use InvariantCulture or Ordinal?

Comment: @DiPix: See my updated answer - the warning is basically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my answer for those who are still looking for a solution to this problem.

I too got the same kind of issue and I modified the code like below.

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchQuery))
        {
            searchQuery = searchQuery.Trim();
            collection = collection.Where(a => a.MainCategory.Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                || a.FirstName.Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                || a.LastName.Contains(searchQuery, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
```